# decision boundary for classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, analysis, evaluation

I have trained my machine learning classification model in Python.
For the result analysis when I am trying to draw a decision  surface or boundary in google colab using sklearn(scikit-learn) inspection module

```
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay
```

I am getting the following error.

[image]

I have  upgraded sklearn

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

After the upgrade sklearn version is 1.0.2

why am I encountering the error and what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

sklearn v1.0.2 does not have DecisionBoundaryDisplay: https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.inspection

sklearn v1.1.3 does: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.inspection

Comment: try `pip install scikit-learn==1.1.3`

Comment: Yes I have tried installing the 1.1.3 version but I am getting the following error 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-learn==1.1.3